# Whether two matrices $M_1$ and $M_2$ are the same, that their entry-wise sums are the same and $M_2=UM_1V$ , where $U$, $V$ are both othogonal

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Given two matrices  $M_1,M_2\in R^{k\times l}$, and there exist two orthogonal matrices $U\in R^{k\times k}$, $V\in R^{l\times l}$ such that $M_2=UM_1V$. If we know the sum of elements of $M_1$ and $M_2$ are the same,
$$\sum\limits_{i,j}m^{(1)}_{i,j}=\sum\limits_{i,j}m^{(2)}_{i,j},$$
where $m^{(1)}$ are the elements of $M_1$ and $m^{(2)}$ are the elements of $M_2$.
Then can we conclude that $M_1=M_2$?

Answer (score 4):

no we can't:
let $A=\begin{pmatrix}0&1\\1&0\end{pmatrix}$ and $B=\begin{pmatrix}a&b\\c&d\end{pmatrix}$ with $a,b,c,d\in \mathbb{R}$

$A\cdot A^T = I \Rightarrow$ A is orthogonal

$A\cdot B \cdot A^T =\begin{pmatrix}d&c\\b&a\end{pmatrix}$

Therefor the sum is the same

qed

edit:
yes the statement 'can imply' is always true... you can simply take I 
$$I\cdot I^T = I \Rightarrow  I $$ is orthogonal
and $A = I\cdot A\cdot I$